# JSON.parse throws "SyntaxError: Unexpected Number" when trying to parse a single string stored in a cookie

Tags: javascript, django

I have this string being stored in a cookie

```
"d967fac49ef2466239168bbbde0a8d755a27ba81$[[\"__json_message\"\05425\054\"This is a message.\"]]"
```

AKA

```
"\"d967fac49ef2466239168bbbde0a8d755a27ba81$[[\\\"__json_message\\\"\\05425\\054\\\"This is a message.\\\"]]\""
```

(for pasting into a console)

but I can't parse it with JSON.parse. However, it works with eval (which is evil). The error is `SyntaxError: Unexpected number`.

Of note are the escaped commas. This was generated with the Django messaging API.

Does anyone know a good regex or other technique that can do this instead?

I first need to unescape the string, (because it's a proper javascript string) and then I need *the array after the dollar* ( `s.substring(s.indexOf("$")+1)` ).

Comment: Erm... Dare I ask what you are expecting to get out of the above string?

Comment: That string does not contain [JSON](http://json.org/) data.

Comment: See here: http://www.json.org/ for the JSON syntax rules.

Comment: What do you want to get? The array after the dollar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for being unclear, I figured it out, thanks to jfriend00's link to [json.org](http://www.json.org). Below is an equivalent string that does work, and what the proper output is supposed to be. It's an JSON array inside of an already encoded string that I needed to unescape easily.

```
var s = JSON.parse("\"d967fac49ef2466239168bbbde0a8d755a27ba81$[[\\\"__json_message\\\"\\u002C25\\u002C\\\"This is a message.\\\"]]\"")
// s = "d967fac49ef2466239168bbbde0a8d755a27ba81$[["__json_message",25,"This is a message."]]"
// and then I get what I actually want
var a = JSON.parse(s.substring(s.indexOf("$")+1))
```

The problem was that when the string was prepared for the cookie the commas were converted to a octal escape codes, which JSON doesn't allow. The error code should have been `JSON forbids octal prefixes`. Once that's taken care of, it'll be fine. So I'll just check for octal escape codes and replace them with hex escape codes.

---

#### TL;DR: "SyntaxError: Unexpected Number" means "SyntaxError: JSON forbids octal prefixes"

---

Here's the function I used

```
var s = "\"d967fac49ef2466239168bbbde0a8d755a27ba81$[[\\\"__json_message\\\"\\05425\\054\\\"This is a message.\\\"]]\""
var re = /\\0([0-7]{2})/g
JSON.parse(s.replace(re, function(m, n){return "\\x"+("0000"+parseInt(n,8).toString(16)).slice(-4)}))
```